# Outlook HTML Emails with Images

Tags: html, css, outlook

Whilst trying to create a responsive email which looks good on retina display devices, I have discovered that Outlook doesn't respect specified criteria for images and displays them as their source dimensions.

For a proof of concept (POC) I have created a banner image as 1200x400, so in emails it would be scaled to 600x200 and as 300x100 on mobile devices.  Sounds good right?

Well, in Outlook it shows it as 1200px wide and there doesn't seem to be anything I can do about it.  Here is the JSFiddle that results in the ghastly Outlook email:
http://jsfiddle.net/hirenshah/rdux8vkg/11/

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
    <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <![endif]-->
                <table class="container" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 600px; background-color: white; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Header Table Start -->
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="alignrightonmobile">
                                        <img src="http://hirenshah.co.uk/poc/logo.png" width="100px" height="75px" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Quote Reference ABC123456</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img class ="banner" src="http://hirenshah.co.uk/poc/banner.png" style="width:auto; max-width:100%;height:auto"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Header Table End -->
                            <!-- Body Table Start -->
                            <!-- Body Table End -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <![endif]-->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    .container {
        width:600px !important;
    }
    .headercolumnright {
        text-align:right !important;
    }
    * {
        font-family: Verdana;
        color:blue !important;}
    .alignrightonmobile {text-align:right !important;}
}
.headercolumnleft {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
    float: left;
    font-size:12pt;
}
.headercolumnright {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
    float: right;
    font-size:12pt;
}
div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
    * {
        font-family: Verdana;
        color:red;}

.alignrightonmobile {text-align:left;}

img.resize {
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has some of the most limited CSS support out of all the popular clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

With that in mind it's easier to build your email to work with Outlook and improve it for all other clients with CSS.

With regards to solving your specific problem, first of all the image you use in the img tag should be optimized for Outlook at 600px wide.

We can then use CSS to set a background-image on the td that contains your image so that you can load in the correct image for those devices that support it, you'll also want to use CSS to hide the image within your td tag on those devices using your media rules.

Comment: Oh what joy Microsoft are!  How would I differentiate between mobile, tablet and desktop?  Some tablets can have the same resolutions as desktops.  I would want the higher resolution images for mobiles and tablets, but then use the standard size for desktops (because of Outlook).

Comment: You  can use media tags when it detects a large device (which won't trigger in Outlook) for example:
@media screen and (min-device-width: 600px)

You generally don't need to worry so much about getting your email to work specifically to devices, rather it's easier (and in my opinion more logical) to target sizes.

Comment: Any chance of an example of how this would work?  I don't know much about using background-image or how to override the default image using CSS.